# sql server cluster

Tags: sql-server

I have a sql server 2000 box in a Active/Passive Clustered Environment. My network guys are Changing private IP on Active and Passive Node : fproddb01(Active Node) fproddb02(Passive Node) from 10.0.0.1 to 192.168.0.1(mask: 255.255.0.0). Also Disabling “Backup” Network Resource under "Cluster Configuration-Networks".

My question is Are they any Risks involved by the Changing the IP's and Disabling the Back Network resource?

Will this have any impact on our backups?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that your team checks out the following KB:

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;244980

Risks of misconfiguration could include not being able to bring up the cluster resources after they are finished with their changes.

Have them pay close attention to the following sections in that KB:

- "Change the IP addresses of SQL Server 2000 failover cluster instances"
- "Change the IP address when the subnet mask for the resources in a Windows cluster is changed"